# Angular js set ng-model within template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, frontend, templating

I'm trying to make my search fields generate automatically, based on config file. 
I wat to make one template for  tag and to set its attrs inside the template (from $scope, of course). So template looks like this:

```
<div>
    <label for = "{{ field.id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "{{ field.id }}" class = "{{ field.css }}" ng-model = "{{ field.model }}" />
</div>
```

If I remove ng-model attr from that snippet everything will work, but if I leave it as I pasted none of the attrs is being "translated" and it look like this when i inspect it.

```
<input type = "text" id = "{{ field.id }}" class = "{{ field.css }}" ng-model = "{{ field.model }}" />
```

but it should look like this:

```
<input type = "text" id = "input1" class = "span3" ng-model = "user.name" />
```

Does anyone has any idea how to solve this thing :)
Thank you all!

Comment: Is it all inside ng-app?

Comment: yes it is inside ng-app. It works fine if i HARDCODE ng-model. but when I want to template it it breaks...

I will add a fiddle or something...
Thank you

Comment: Here is a fiddle... it is hard to explain in fiddle but... here it is http://jsfiddle.net/utQwU/